# Android Service Wont stop in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a service that I start and bind to from an Activity. In the Activity's OnDestroy method I unbind to the service. The service Displays a notification and I use startForeground() to put it in the foreground. In the Service's onUnbind() method I call stopself() and stopForeground(true). But It appears that the service doesn't stop working. The app is closed and the notification is gone but the android memory monitor in android studio keeps going. Why is this happening? If I create a function in the service that calls stopForeground(), and call it before the OnDestroy of the Activity then the app closes fine. The memory monitor stops.

MainActivity in OnCreate():

```
   service = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Service.class);


    service.setAction("START");
    startService(service);

    if(myservice == null)
    {
        Intent k = new Intent(this,Service.class);
        bindService(k, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

MainActivity in OnDestroy()

```
         unbindService(myConnection);
```

Service OnCreate()

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setAction("new");
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);


        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Myservice")
                .setTicker("service")
                .setContentText("Monitoring")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true).build();

        startForeground(101, notification);
```

Comment: "but the android memory monitor in android studio keeps going" -- I do not know what "keeps going" means to you. Your process does not go away just because you stop a service. [Your process will continue to run for a while](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes). Similarly, any other ongoing work that you set up, such as threads that you forked yourself, continue to run. If your service did this sort of thing, you need to clean that stuff up in `onDestroy()` or some other likely point.

Comment: @CommonsWare- Why does this problem only come when I use a Notification and StartForground()?

Comment: Since I do not know what "this problem" is, I cannot answer that. Please consider editing your question and explaining, in greater detail, what "the android memory monitor in android studio keeps going" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare-What I mean is even after I close the app the memory monitor keeps ploting, showing that the app is still using memory. Before I added the Notification and StartForground(), When I close the app the memory monitor will go stop ploting.

Comment: The app is still using memory in either case. Again, your process will be around after the service is destroyed. Why the IDE tool is showing a difference here, I cannot say.

Comment: I have similar problem, in service on onTaskRemoved calling stopForeground(true) notification is close bunt timer with 1sek interval works all the time. This behavior observe only on samsung devices with android 6.x or 4.4.2, other devices kill the timer.

Answer (score 1):

1)service is running in background so `onDestroy()` method you need to call method on service.

```
stopSelf();
```

2) you want to close service on app close then you need to  implement `onTaskRemoved()` and call

```
stopSelf();
```

3)And you Want to stop service on Activity Close then  `onDestroy()` method of Activity you need to call follow code.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent serviceIntent=new Intent(this,ServiceClass.class);
    stopService(serviceIntent);
}
```